Maximum number of non-adjacent regions of hyperplane arrangement
What is the maximum number of pairwise non-adjacent regions of an arrangement of $k$-hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$?
EDIT: Any region is a $n$-dimensional polytope, in fact a convex cone, and two regions are adjacent if they share a $n-1$-dimensional face. In other words there exist a segment starting in one region and ending in the other region that crosses exactly one hyperplane.
In particular I'm interested in the generic central arrangement (meaning that any $i$-tuple of hyperplanes intersect in a distinct subspace of codimension $i$, for $i<n$, and in the origin for $i=n$), whose characteristic polynomial is $\chi(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-1)^i\binom{k}{i}t^i+(-1)^n\binom{k-1}{n-1}t^n$.
For graph theorists this could also be seen as finding the maximal cardinality of a vertex packing of the adjacency graph of the regions.

How is adjacency defined?

If we arrange the hyperplanes to form an $n$-dimensional grid pattern, then we get around $(\frac kn)^n$ regions, and the graph is bipartite so about half of them are independent. If $n$ is fixed as $k \to \infty$, then this is $\Theta(k^n)$, which is asymptotically optimal.
